# react добавить скролл

Tags: reactjs, прокрутка

Мне нужно добавить скролл, я делал через css, но это сами понимаете...
Дальше я нашел библиотеку react-scroll, но она какая-то старая, там все примеры на классах.
В чем основаная суть, у менять есть скролл и две кнопки "вправо" и "влево", при нажатии на кнопки я не должен переходить куда-то до какого-то конкретного элемента, а просто вправо например на 100px
Можно ли такое отыскать, подскажите мож кто сталкивался

Comment: слишком обстрактная задача. Пишите сами или оплатите, вам сделают.

Comment: я просил лишь подсказать направление, а не написать код, типа какую библиотеку можно заюзать, может кто-то делал ппохожее, просто горизонтальный скролл да еще и с кнопочками это не то что очень часто используемая вещь, поэтому найти у меня пока ничего не получается разве что вот это https://asmyshlyaev177.github.io/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu/?path=/story/scrollmenu-simple--simple